# Check if symbol is in core language

Tags: core-language, symbols

How can I check if a symbol is pre-defined by Mathematica, in a way that's backwards compatible with old versions?

i.e. I would like some `CoreLanguageQ[x_Symbol]` which matches     `CoreLangaugeQ[Print]`, but not `CoreLanguageQ[f]`

Then it can be used to help make code backwards compatible, eg.

```
If[!CoreLanguageQ[Echo], Echo[x_]:= (Print[x];x)]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something like ``CoreLanguageQ[x_Symbol] := Context[x]==="System`"`` ?

Comment: Mathematica's "core language" is ill defined. As @QuantumDot notes, the best you can probably do is check whether a symbol is in the ``"System`"`` context. Package development aspects of the language weren't terribly well designed so the language is somewhat bloated in this regard. It does not have a tight "core language" like most modern languages.

Comment: My definition is 'any symbol that's defined when I restart the kernel'. I will try `System`, thankyou.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can look it up using `WolframLanguageData`, which has a list of all pre-defined symbols:

```
ClearAll[CoreLanguageQ]
SetAttributes[CoreLanguageQ, HoldAll]
CoreLanguageQ[x_] := With[{name = SymbolName[x]}, CoreLanguageQ[name]]
CoreLanguageQ[x_String] := With[{
   names = WolframLanguageData[All, "Name"]
   }, MemberQ[names, x]]

CoreLanguageQ[Plot]
(* Out: True *)

CoreLanguageQ[Plott]
(* Out: False *)
```

Looking at the context of the symbol is also a viable approach. However, the `WolframLanguageData` approach is appealing because the documentation states that

> WolframLanguageData[] gives a list of all Wolfram Language symbols.

Which is to say, the list returned by this function is by definition Wolfram Language. This is as close as a definition of "core language" that we can come.

For the problem in the updated question, it would seem appropriate to check if a symbol exists in the `System` context like QuantumDot suggests in a comment.

The only backward compatible way to use this would be to create lists of functions available for specific versions and include them in your code. For example:

```
names = WolframLanguageData[All, "Name"];
versionIntroduced = WolframLanguageData[All, "VersionIntroduced"];
allowed = Pick[names, Thread[versionIntroduced <= 10]];
```

In this code, `allowed` holds all the symbols that exist in version 10, presuming that no symbol previously introduced was removed.

Comment: Ah I apologise. This answers my original question, but now I see that my original question wasn't what I wanted to ask. `WolframLanguageData[]` is a relatively new function and I want to use this for backwards compatability; eg. `If[!CoreLanguageQ[Echo], Echo[x_]:= (Print[x];x)]`. I've updated my question

Comment: @Joe ok, then QuantumDot's suggestion seems more appropriate.

Comment: Yes I think so. Thankyou for your solution though it's nice

Comment: You might want to add some AtomQ check. This produces an error for me when x is not atomic.