# How to list all user-defined symbols?

Tags: symbols, contexts

I create a lot of symbols, and then I move on to my next set of manipulations. I noticed that symbols from prior sessions are still around. I have no idea how many symbols are in my context, but there must be a lot of them. How can I see what symbols I have lying around?

I see that

```
Names["*"]
```

will give me a list of all symbols, but that includes the upper-case system symbols, which I don't want to see.

Comment: [Relevant on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166027/list-all-user-defined-variables-functions-in-a-notebook-in-mathematica/6166044), and a [possible duplicate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37316/generate-a-list-of-all-user-defined-functions-including-their-argument-patterns)

Comment: Also related: [(175573)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175573/121), and perhaps [(1474)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1474/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

User defined symbols/functions are in the `` Global` `` [context](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html):

```
a = 1;
b[x_] := a x^2;
c[x_] := f[x];

Names["Global`*"]
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "f", "x"}

Comment: I would argue that, in fact, neither `f` nor `x` are user-defined symbols in your example. I would only consider `a`, `b`, `c` to be. Given the accept, I guess OP would disagree with me though.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The other problem I see is that not all user-defined symbols *are* in the Global context.  This probably suffices for many purposes but it's not really robust.